# Does Google crawl AJAX API calls?

Tags: google, googlebot

We have been monitoring our logs for Googlebot and there are many requests to  API calls (requests via AJAX) which are used to fetch the page and not the complete page url.

How does Google understand these URLS?

Comment: See also: [How do I stop Google from indexing AJAX calls within Javascript?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104011/can-google-index-ajax-calls-within-javascript)

Comment: See also: [Does the Google spider render JavaScript?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript)